github actions does not work for some pull request
enter image description here
help why in the repository one pull request creates an action and the second pull request does not create actions as if the test.yml file does not exist actions does not even launch and does not appear although it should be launched for any pull request
All branches naturally have workflows and test.yml

If possible, please provide the link of your GitHub repo
